# Valve heater voltage without separate windings

Tags: power-supply, vacuum-tube

I want to build a simple single-ended valve amplifier from an old TV.

I am facing a problem, that I don't know how to produce the 13V, 300mA supply for the heater.(PCL86)
I am using the mains transformer directly from the old TV. But while other amplifiers I see have a transformer with separate windings for a heater, this one only has one primary and one secondary winding.

The TV obviously had solved this problem somehow, so how could I solve this most easily?

Comment: @DaveTweed I have found another, smaller transformator mounted on the mainboard, could that be it? Or if it is as you say how could I easily produce that voltage necessary?

Comment: I doubt that there would be a separate power transformer. It's more likely that it's a vertical output transformer or even an audio output transformer. But there's no reason you couldn't add a second power transformer yourself. 12.6 VAC transformers are very readily available.

Comment: Be aware that tubes are *very* sensitive to their heater temperature hence heater voltage. 12,6V is not 13V. Overheating a tube can shorten dramatically their life time.

Comment: @greg I have a 12V nominal, 12,3V actual DC supply, so it should be fine, but thanks for the tip, also in the PCL86 datasheet there is 13V / 300mA for heating.(Seemed strange to me too.)

Comment: Comment on what Dave said: A family of tubes had a common filament CURRENT specification and more or less filament power was achieved by varying the required voltage. That way a string of eg 300 mA tubes could have all their filaments in series and then operate the string from an HV DC source - eg one derived by rectifying the AC mains. More common with 110 VAC mains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the TV put all of the heaters in series directly across the AC line input. Very common in cheap "hot chassis" designs.

There's no reason you couldn't add a second power transformer yourself. 12.6 VAC transformers are very readily available.

Or you could use a separate DC 12V supply for testing purposes — Heaters don't care whether they're getting AC or DC.

Comment: The appropriate search term for a 12.6 VAC transformer is "filament transformer".